# How to store query multiple result in shell script variable(Array)?

Tags: bash, ksh, sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a query and store **every row** result in an array element in ksh (maybe bash).
I do:

```
result=($($PATH_UTI/querysh "
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT columnA,columnb FROM user.comunication;"))
```

I have that:

```
row1 = HOUSE CAR
row2 = DOC   CAT
echo "${result[1]}" and it gives me HOUSE
```

But I would like to get:

```
echo "${result[1]}" gives: "HOUSE CAR"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change default separator `IFS` to split data by end of line character and disable globbing with `set -f` to avoid issues with strings containing e.g. `*` or `?`:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ set -f
$ result=( $(printf "HOUSE CAR\nDOC   CAT") )
$ echo "${result[0]}"
HOUSE CAR
$ echo "${result[1]}"
DOC   CAT
```

Note that both changes will stay in effect for the rest of the script unless changed back.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash you can use `mapfile` (it should be tested with your actual result):

```bsh
# note that the parenthesis are not needed
$ result="HOUSE CAR
DOC   CAT"
$ mapfile -t arr < <(printf "%s" "$result")
$ echo "${arr[0]}" # or 1 if the first row is empty
HOUSE CAR
```